# How do I Calculate this Estimated Weighted Return?

Tags: calculation, portfolio

I am trying to figure out how to calculate an estimated weighted return. For example, imagine I have the following portfolio:

```
| ETF   | Quantity | Value     | Weight | Estimated Return | Estimated Weighted Return |
|-------|----------|-----------|--------|------------------|---------------------------|
| VTI   | 5        | $1,127.10 | 21.4%  | 9.04%            | ?                         |
| VOO   | 7        | $2,872.52 | 54.5%  | 16.7%            | ?                         |
| VOX   | 10       | $1,269.60 | 24.1%  | 8.78%            | ?                         |
|-------|----------|-----------|--------|------------------|---------------------------|
| Total |          | $5,269.22 | 100.0% | 11.50%           | ?                         |
```

I know a) the weight of each ETF in my portfolio b) the estimated return of each ETF, c) the estimated return is just a simple average. But, how do I:

- Calculate the estimated weighted return per ETF
- Calculate the average estimated weighted return for my portfolio.

Thank you

Comment: Make the weight percentages, instead, as parts per hundred. Then ((21.4 * 9.08%) + (54.5 * 16.7%) + (24.1 * 8.78*)) / 100. But here is a software that time-weights the portfolio but actually projects the result as to year-end: http://www.kbhscape.com/kbh.htm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're really after the total expected return for the portfolio, which is NOT just a simple average of the component expected returns. You can do that one of two ways:

- Take a weighted average of the ETF returns `(9.04% * 21% + 16.7% * 55%...)`
- Calculate the *absolute* return for each ETF, sum, and divide by the total amount:

  ```
  9.05% * 1,127.1 + 16.7% * 2,872.52 + ... 
  ----------------------------------------
                 5,269.22
  ```

Since the total return is basically a weighted average weighted by *amount* instead of *percentage*, the result is the same for either method. You should get a total expected return of `13.15%`.